# How to redirect remote computer's output file to local using psexec

Tags: remote

i can run remote commands without any problem and get output to my local machine with psexec. but one of the command can export result as xml so i also send this parameter to save output as xml. during the process it shows information about progress but all in text format. the file i want to read is xml when i  try to redirect this xml output to my local it doesnt. it only redirects this text based message on console.

PsExec.exe \dc01  cmd /c dcdiag /test:DNS /DNSALL /e /v >test.txt this way i can get output in text format without any problem.

PsExec.exe \dc01  cmd /c  dcdiag /test:DNS /DNSALL /e /v  /x:test.xml   but i need to send this x:/ paramter and log file name to remote computer to get output as xml format.

PsExec.exe \dc01  cmd /c  dcdiag /test:DNS /DNSALL /e /v  /x:test.xml  >test.xml  when i run this way it saves my local machine the output on the console screen(which is text based not xml) so i want to get output file as xml.

how can i do it ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its possible to set output path through network

if your command succesfully generates a local xml file test.xml why not add a path to your mashine:

```
/x:\\yourMashine_fqdn\c$\path\to\file.xml
```

as an alternative you can write a script with a copy command after dcdiag.

it doesnt matter if the script is local bcause psexec can copy it to the remote mashine with the -c parameter